# Appending domain name in the csv data rows after finding which rows does not have the domain after user name

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, append

I have a data set which contains email address column and some of its values does not contain the "@.gmail.com" string. how can I append this string to those values after finding them in the dataset
I have tried to find the rows  that have the string in it, as a newbie, following is the code

```
        import re
        import pandas as pd
        file=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
        xx = "@gmail.com"
        r1 = re.findall(r"^\w+",xx)
         print(r1)
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: import pandas import re file=
xx = "@gmail.com"
r1 = re.findall(r"^\w+",xx)
print(r1)

Comment: @ Leyff da  I have provided the code I have completed...help me with the next part.

Comment: The mrzasa's answer didnt work ?

Comment: I wanted to use the regexp for doing this...

Comment: Why do you want to use regexp?

Comment: to learn the use of regex in Python!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to iterate and use good old `if` and `endswith` (no regexps). I prepared a simple example (no CSV):

```
t = ['a', 'b', 'c@gmail.com']
for i, s in enumerate(t):
    if not s.endswith('@gmail.com'):
        t[i] = s + '@gmail.com'

print(t)
```

Comment: I have to modify the records in the .CSV file.